# How does a CSS rule override another CSS rule?

Tags: html, css, dom

So, this is what I'm doing:

```
#id-form td {
padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#particular-td {
border: 1px solid black;
text-align: center;
background-color: #DFDFDF;
height: 30px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

I have a table `#id-form`, on which I set all `td`s to have `padding-bottom: 10px`.
But on one special occasion, I want a particular `td` to have `padding: 10px` in all directions, which I set in the `#particular-td`.

Obviously, I put the CSS styling in sequence in an external file.
But the rendered CSS only has `padding-bottom`, and `padding: 10px` appears to be overridden!?

*Please explain:*
*How and why is this happening?*
*How should I arrange these rules to solve my problem (other than inline styling)?*

EDIT: I removed `'table'` before `#id-form` in table. I was never using this, I just mentioned it here to be able to explain it better.

Comment: CSS isn't my strong point, however, if you want THAT particular CSS element to have a padding, why not put it in the 'style' of the element itself? That's sure to override all the other things.

Comment: @ATaylor inline CSS is not a manageable solution.

Comment: See [CSS3 selectors: 9. Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity).

Comment: You don't need the `table` element selector before `#id-form`, as there can only be one element with `#id-form` in the page and the extra selector will slow it down ever so slightly. Just for future reference! :)

Comment: Edited the CSS, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because of [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). A selector's weighting is evaluated based on the components that make it up, with `id`'s given a weighting of 100, `class`es with a weighting of 10, and `element` selectors with weighting of 1.

So in your example:

```
table#id-form td
```

Has a weighting of 102 (`table#id` is 101 and `td` is 1), whereas this:

```
#particular-td
```

Has a weighting of 100. If you change your second to this:

```
#id-form #particular-td
```

You will get a weighting of 200 which will override the previous selector. Only as a last resort should you ever use `!important`, as this pretty much prevents you from overriding it further down the line.

Comment: Thanks bro. Thanks a lot. It has been a pain for me to understand this stuff earlier!

Comment: Adding to this: Inline-CSS always has the 'highest weight' unless you use `!important`

Answer (score 8):

This has to do with specificity. `table#id-form td` is more specific than `#particular-td`. A rule with higher specificity has precedence over a rule with lower specificity.

Here are a few resources to get you started on understanding how it works:

- [Smashing Magazine article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)
- [W3C spec on specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)
- [Specificity calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

**About using !important, as suggested by others:**

One might be tempted to use the `!important` keyword to sort this out, but that is rarely a good idea:

1. It becomes a pain to maintain/troubleshoot
2. It breaks the normal flow of CSS
3. The rule cannot be overridden by other rules later on

It might take a few minutes to read up on specificity, but it will be well worth the time spent when you've got a grasp of it.

Comment: +1 for encouraging further reading - before I understood specificity I used to spend countless hours bashing my head wondering why it didn't just "cascade" as I expected.

Comment: \+1 for the specificity calculator.

Comment: If you are stuck with `!important` spaghetti, note that one way `!important` properties can be overridden is with other `!important` properties [when the ruleset that contains them has a higher specificity](https://jsbin.com/puvazu/edit?css,output). **Don't** actually do this though!

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways, either add !important after your padding for the particular-td:

```
padding: 10px !important;
```

OR, your selector altered like so:

```
table#id-form td#particular-td {
border: 1px solid black;
text-align: center;
background-color: #DFDFDF;
height: 30px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Both are fine. Personally I don't like the use of !important if I can avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, I have added !important to your css, in this mode can ovveride padding of table#id-form td

```
#particular-td {
border: 1px solid black;
text-align: center;
background-color: #DFDFDF;
height: 30px;
padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Would this work in IE as well? I have heard that this creates some problem with IE?

Comment: Using `!important` is not the way to go here. That should really be the solution of last resort.

Comment: I agree Christofer, plus here I'm trying to know the reason of this overriding, because no matter what, I can resort to inline styling at the end.