# CSS: !important not overriding other rules

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the font color in my navigation bar. I use bootstrap and my own stylesheets. 
I want my font to be red, so I'm trying to override every other rule with the help of **!important** (other things failed as well). But the color stays grey. Those are the computed values on my element from chrome developer tools:

- color: hsl(0, 0%, 60%);
- .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand - #999
- <del>a - #428bca</del>
- <del>a:-webkit-any-link - -webkit-link</del>
- <del>nav - red !important</del>
- <del>body - #333</del>

How is it possible that **!important** gets overriden by styling with **class selector** and  how to make my font red?

(answer is that !important only overrides styles on the same element you apply it to. It doesn't make the element's descendants inherit from it) - from comments.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could add your actual CSS. I'm not entirely sure what those bullets mean in CSS.

Comment: Only Chrome (Webkit/Blink) ?

Comment: @jsalonen, well, this is my css: html{color: red !important;}, everything else comes from bootstrap.css.

Comment: You don't have to use important normally.

Comment: @Xatenev, I even tried ids.

Comment: If possible, never use `!important`. Its bad practice usually applied because people do not understand how CSS rules get overriden.

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780511/how-does-a-css-rule-override-another-css-rule

Comment: @jsalonen, this was't a question about whether using !important is a good practice, I know it isn't and I tried classes and then ids beforehand.

Comment: @jsalonen: Neither of the two questions you've linked to are relevant.

Comment: I could have sworn this was asked a couple of days ago. The answer is that `!important` only overrides styles on the same element you apply it to. It doesn't make the element's descendants inherit from it.

Comment: @BoltClock imho they are relevant: if he had known how CSS srules override each other, he would not even had used `!important` in the first place. Please, if you find that question from yesterday, add a link.

Comment: @jsalonen: Still, calling the first link a duplicate is just plain wrong. These are two completely different questions.

Comment: I called it a possible duplicate. Given the extra information I agree: it is not a duplicate. If you have some other candidate for duplicate please add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: this worked, thanks. why does it work while !important doesn't?

Comment: You were simply not addressing the right elements.

Comment: not addresssing right elements while using html{color: red !important;} while font color is inheritable property?

Comment: @lakesare I think bootstrap is using !important sometimes, and probably these !important things come AFTER ur "html{color...}" so they override yours.