# How do CSS rules override

Tags: css, css-selectors

maybe regarded as duplicate for [How does a CSS rule override another CSS rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780511/how-does-a-css-rule-override-another-css-rule) but in my markup

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    this is content ...
  </div>
</div>
```

and stylesheet

```
div .child { deceleration }
.parent div { deceleration }
```

What is causing

```
.parent div { deceleration }
```

override

```
div .child { deceleration }
```

as the later is more specific, I think.
thanks in advance

Comment: you may try with `!important`

Comment: It has the same specificity http://specificity.keegan.st/, but comes later in code, that's all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the [Cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#cascading-order) CSS has a decision algorithm to find the applied declaration in case of conflicts between all the selectors that match the element:

### **Upper Items in the list have priority and precede lower ones**

1. Declarations marked as **'!important'**
2. Declarations in **author's style sheet** (provided by website)

   > specificity = Concatenating a & b & c with the following order and weights:
   >   a = 100 * ( number of ID attributes in the selector )
   >   b = 10 * ( number of Class attributes (or Pseudo-classes) in the selector )
   >   c = 1 * ( number of tag names (or Pseudo-elements) in the selector )

   - **Higher specificity** (first)

     - Rules in **main style sheet**
       *In case of equal specificity:*

       - **Downer presence** in style sheet / document
       - **Upper presence** in style sheet / document
     - Rules in **imported style sheets**
       *In case of equal specificity:*

       - **Downer presence** in style sheet / document
       - **Upper presence** in style sheet / document
   - **Lower specificity** (next)

     - Rules in **main style sheet**
       *In case of equal specificity:*

       - **Downer presence** in style sheet / document
       - **Upper presence** in style sheet / document
     - Rules in **imported style sheets**
       *In case of equal specificity:*

       - **Downer presence** in style sheet / document
       - **Upper presence** in style sheet / document
3. Declarations in [**user style sheet**](http://dbaron.org/css/user/)
   [ Like part 2 ]
4. Declarations in **User-Agent style sheet** (provided by browser)
   [ Like part 2 ]

---

**Note 1**

Using `style` attribute of an element will be equal to ID-based selector that is specified at the end of the style sheet.

So:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="color:red">My content</div>
```

is equal to:

```
<div id="myDiv">My content</div>

#myDiv{    /* last line of stylesheet */
    color:red
}
```

**Note 2**

Some HTML attributes are stylistic like

- ALIGN
- WIDTH / HEIGHT
- HIDDEN

these attributes are translated to the corresponding CSS rules with **specificity** equal to 1 and assumed to be put at the start of the **author's style sheet**

So:

```
<div id="myDiv" align="center">My content</div>
```

is equal to:

```
<div>My content</div>

div{    /* first line of stylesheet */
    text-align:center
}
```

### So to answer you question

That is because of downer presence of

```
.parent div { deceleration }
```

and if you put it upper like this

```
.parent div { deceleration }
div .child { deceleration }
```

then

```
div .child { deceleration }
```

would apply instead.

Comment: Woah  , you are a fast typer xD

Comment: Thanks but I had part of this in my own educational documentations :)

Comment: Please edit your answer because `100 * (number of id attributes) +10 * (number of class attributes) + ...` is misleading. Counterexample: http://jsbin.com/getuneyamu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @nishanths +1 for helpful comment. I will add an edit right now

Comment: Notes 1 and 2 are both incorrect. For Note 1, If a stylesheet contained `body #myDiv { color:blue }` the style attribute would trump it, but `#myDiv { color:red }` at the end of the stylesheet would not. For Note 2, those attributes have a specificity equal to **0**, not 1. So `* { text-align:left }` in the stylesheet trumps the "align" attribute on div elements.

Comment: @Alohci: That's exactly what's stated in CSS1 though. An oversimplification at best. CSS2 and up express it in terms of specificity values, which helps. The real question is why Trix chose to base his entire answer on a level of CSS that's been obsolete *since the 90s* and is thus riddled with inconsistencies and incompatibilities with current standards (like the `*` selector in your counter-example)...