# styles property is not working in the component metadata in angular 2?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am new in Angular 2, I am creating a demo app and want to set the `styles` property in the `component` metadata for all labels in `contact.component.html`.

I added `styles: ['label { font-weight: bold;color:red }']` to solve my problem but the CSS effects is not displaying on my views.

I know i can use `styleUrls: [ '../css/contact.component.css' ]` but don't want to do so. I want to learn set the styles property in the component metadata.

Please suggest why this effect is not displaying on views?

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: '../views/contact.component.html',
  styles: ['label { font-weight: bold;color:red }']
})
```

**contact.component.html:**

```
<h2 highlight>Contact of {{userName}}</h2>
<h2 myHighlight>This is custom my directive</h2>
<div *ngIf="msg" class="msg">{{msg}}</div>
<form *ngIf="contacts" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #contactForm="ngForm">
  <h3 >{{ contact.name | awesome }}</h3>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="contact.name" name="name"  #name="ngModel" >
    <div [hidden]="name.valid" class="alert alert-danger">Name is required </div>
  </div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="EmailId">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="contact.email" name="email" #email="ngModel">
    <div [hidden]="email.valid" class="alert alert-danger">email is required </div>
</div>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!contactForm.form.valid">Save</button>
</form>
```

See the snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there are no global styles that overrule your local style?

Comment: styles defined in the decorator should have priority over global css, so if he doesn't have `label { color: grey!important; }` somewhere, that wouldn't be the case, or?

Comment: @lexith That's right, but to me the code looks fine, therefore the problem has to lie somewhere else. I don't think `important` is necessary. `label[for][for] { }` might also work. Component styles have higher specificity, but you can increase specificity of global styles without `!important`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
styles: [`
   .form-group label { 
     font-weight: bold;
     color: red; 
   }
`]
```

Read the [styles guide](https://angular.io/styleguide).

Comment: There's no difference in your solution. The ` are just needed for multiline strings, which is not his problem.

Comment: @lexith  Large, inline templates and styles obscure the component's purpose and implementation, reducing readability and maintainability.

Comment: Yes okay, i too wouldn't use inline templates / styles but how will this help him with his problem?

Comment: @lexith ok, let him change the selector. So it should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks@Roman C  &&  lexith,  When I have added styles: [`.form-group label {  font-weight: bold;  color: red;  }`] then it's working, but I am unable to understand why without `form-group` this is not working?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma You'd better read [how css rules overrides](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12780511/573032)